# Product of two absolutely convergent improper integrals is absolutely convergent

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Let $f$ and $g$ be such that $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ and $\int_{1}^{\infty}g(x)\,dx$ are absolutely convergent. I need to prove that $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)\,dx$ is absolutely convergent.
It's sufficient to prove that if $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ absolutely converges then $\int_{1}^{\infty}f^{2}(x)\,dx$ converges. I think this is easier to prove. However, I don't have an idea how to start out yet.
Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)={1\over x\sqrt{x-1}}$. Does $\int_1^\infty f^2(x)dx$ converge?

Comment: @BarryCipra: No. So this statement isn't even true. I was asked to prove it in a homework assignment and have had trouble finding the proof.

Comment: It's good you had trouble! You might try adding an assumption that $f$ is *bounded*.